# Rails 5 enum inside model's Concerns generates NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, include, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport-concern

Rails 5 here.

I tried without luck to load a concern inside my User model (devise model).
The `include Levelable` works without any problem on other models.
Do I have to configure a special config/helper/initializer regarding this special model to make it work?

Model concern Levelable is used by models User and Client

```
#models/concerns/levelable.rb 
require 'active_support/concern'

module Levelable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    enum level: { beginner: 0, intermediate: 1, advanced: 2, very_advanced: 3 }
  end
end
```

And the model (shortened for readability)

```
#models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  include Levelable

  acts_as_messageable
end
```

This setup result is a: `NameError: uninitialized constant User::Levelable` 
Same error happens on Client model so I guess something is not working with my concerns load.
I already tried to autoload the path inside `config/application.rb` without any change.

I can not figure out how to make the load of the Concerns works, any help would be great. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem some time ago and after some digging I found out that my concern files where named using the Capitalize form (for some crazy reason).

So I renamed them from `Searchable.rb` to `searchable.rb` and it's all done! :)

PS. IF you use git/github, the diff isn't case sensitive so if you rename them from `Levelable.rb` to `levelable.rb` it won't appear in the `git status`.

Cheers

Comment: Obviously that was it. Thank you for the hint!